# Using Netbeans to create a project

Tags: user-interface, inheritance, netbeans

I have been using JGrasp for about 3 years which I am use to creating classes, Main classes, GUI classes which would be contained in the same folder in order to compile.

Now I started using NetBeans, and I pretty new to creating projects, creating the types of classes I will be using.

So my question is.. If i was to create a simple project which involves 3 classes, Person (super class), Employee (which inherits Person) and a Date class (which is associated with the Employer class).

I then also create a simple Gui interface on top of this class structure in order to take in details based on Person details and/or Employee details, and then a choice to display them on text area. The GUI contains 2 classes (UserDetails (takes in the details, and DisplayDetails (displays the details).

Would all this be contained into 1 project? And would the normal classes be contained a package different from the GUI classes?

Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 5 classes, you can get by without a package structure. But you might aw well start thinking about a higher level of organization to your program code.

Put your data objects in one package--com.you.program.data

Put your GUI in at least one other package--com.you.program.ui

Main program could be in com.you.program or com.you.program.main or, if it is easier, just put the main in the UI package if its mostly just firing up the UI.

Note that com.you is, theoretically your webside backwards and 'program' is the name of the program you are working on.

*NOTE*

There is a theoretical discussion that goes on about whether to divide the business logic of the application from the UI that connects it to the user. Doing this makes it easier to put a different UI on the front of things and allow, for example, a Swing interface for users running on their desktops/laptops and a Web interface for users running browsers on their tablets and phones.

Its not a bad idea and one way to isolate that is to make two projects in your IDE. One holds the UI layer code and one holds the Business layer code. This is a well defined pattern and works well.

Another way to isolate the UI and business layers is to use packages but the IDE will not enforce any dependency management. But on a small project it does work well. You have to be disciplined. (And never forget how small projects grow into large ones with time and they do it unexpectedly.)

If you use projects, make sure there are no dependencies where the Business layer project uses the the UI layer without implementing a well defined pattern, perhaps an Observer (the GOF pattern). The UI layer, however, can and will be dependent on the Business layer. You can also enforce this during the stand-alone build process with a tool like Maven or Gradle, that excels at this.

No matter how you do it, you have to think about what is business logic. If you add some Javascript code to a browser or some code to a Swing GUI or a phone app to check that the phone number is a valid format for the country, its probably not going to bite you. If, however, you add code to the front end, in a similar way, that directly calls the phone number database to verify the first few digits are valid, you have stepped over the line. In those cases, that logic needs to be in the Business section and the UI part needs to call it to check that phone number. This is always a hard question to resolve with lots of edge cases.

Comment: OK thanks, it does clear this structure alot more. You mean by the Main class which is the GUI class for Netbeans to run the application with? If so, does this Main class preferably should be in a different package (as you suggested com.you.main) by itself? Thanks again

Comment: According to [this site](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-intro.html) you should create two projects to create an efficient application. So I could put my data classes into a Java Class Library project, and the GUI classes into a Java Application project? Thanks